# What natural ingredient besides honey and fats can I use to bind a mixture of powders together?

Tags: ingredient-selection

So I need to turn super food powders into something more tangible, like a stick form. Honey seems to not be that effective and has a lot of sugar and fats melt quite easily. Water obviously not a good option. What else could I try? Thanks so much for any answers!

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail about why you wish to "bind a mixture of powders together?" I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Is your goal to turn super food powder into something that you can chew instead of making a "smoothie" as it was intended for?

Comment: If your powders contain gluten (or some other protein that binds well), you could probably make them into a biscuit or cracker.

Comment: Maybe peanut butter - it is thick and sticky enough to bind well, but mixing powders with it can balance the stickiness and make a more stable end result.

Comment: What kind of ambient temperature do you expect when you refer to melting?

Comment: OK, this is over an year old and the OP has not clarified. So everybody is jumping on the bandwagon to suggest completely different ideas, each of them producing an end result with completely different uses. Continuing that way, we could list half a kitchen's worth of ingredients and still not find an answer which works "as intended", simply because we don't know what is intended. I'm closing this as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nut butter, caramelized sugar, marshmellows or gelatin to bind things together, but it really depends on what is in the powder you are trying to solidify.

Answer (score 1):

Several options come to mind:

- Gelatine: Mix the powder with water and gelatine to get something ranging from Jell-O to gummy bears
- Eggs 1: Mix with eggs and fry. If that is too soft try adding some flour
- Eggs 2: Mix with eggs, fill into a metal pipe with one closed end and put it into a water bath
- Cereal and honey: Mix with cereal and honey, form bars and pour on more cereal to remove stickiness. That way you get a cereal/granola bar

Edit:
Or you make pipes from sugar, chocolate, waffles, etc. and fill them with a mixture of your superfood and whatever you like. Seal the pipes using the same material as glue.

Comment: Great reply. You can also cook cerial/granolawith some fruit, like banana that put all together.

Answer (score -1):

I know that vegans and vegetarians use apple sauce instead of eggs.  There are articles out there explaining how to do the maths, and I'm sure you'll find your happiness there...
Hope this helps

Comment: Could you link to such an article? Or at least explain how this might work, rough ratios, etc?